# Replace vector of species codes with species common name

Tags: string, character, match, substitution

I have a list of 370 species with their common names (character string) as well as species codes (numeric). I am trying to replace/substitute the species codes in my abundance matrix with the species common name. I cannot find the correct code for this. I tried 'match' and '%s' but it didn't work.

Comment: what language or DB are you using to accomplish this? What have you tried